# SSMS/SQL-Express - edit user - password field is missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, ssms-2016

I'm having a strange problem with the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, logged in as Administrator on an SQL Server Express-Server 13. When I want to create or edit an database-user the password-fields are missing (see screenshot). As I saw from other screenshots in the area with the red question-mark there should be the fields for the password or fields for an certificate (depending on the user-type). What am I doing wrong?

[image: screenshot from SMSS]

Comment: Passwords are usually on the login (under the security node) - not the user

Comment: In the object-explorer this is from "SQLEXPRESS > databases > database-name > security > users > user-name" Is that not the right place?

Comment: I don't have a running sqlexpress version right now, but I don't think it's different from other versions; where there should be a `security` >  `logins` - then you create a login (username/password etc) which you then can assign users to.

Comment: I have the following nodes under security: users, roles, schemas, asymetric keys, symetric keys, certificates.

Comment: Do you not have a security node outside the specific database?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: You're right - didn't notice that separate security-folder. Thanks!